# Fiware IoT Broker and IoT Configuration Manager XML Validation

Tags: fiware

I figured out I had to have another GE, the IoT Configuration Manager working parallel to the IoT Broker in order to manage the entities from which we will get data. Now, it seems that the XMLValidator code is giving me some trouble. I registered an entity via HTTP POST osgi9 directly with the configuration manager. Then I try to access it by communicating via osgi10 with the IoT broker. The IoT Broker communicates with the IoT DIscovery service and gets a response, but then the XMLValidator says the XML is wrong even tough it clearly is not.

This is the IoT Broker asking for the availability of a resource to the IoT ConfMan:

```
2014-11-27 10:31:13,682 | INFO | (HttpConnectionClient.java:initializeConnection:170) | Output 

Stream: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<discoverContextAvailabilityRequest>
<entityIdList>
<entityId isPattern="false">
<id>Dorm</id>
</entityId>
</entityIdList>
<attributeList/>
<restriction>
<scope>
<operationScope>
<scopeType>IncludeAssociations</scopeType>
<scopeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">SOURCES</scopeValue></operationScope>
</scope>
</restriction>
</discoverContextAvailabilityRequest>
```

Then IoT Broker gets:

```
2014-11-27 10:31:13,947 | INFO | (HttpConnectionClient.java:initializeConnection:188) | 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><discoverContextAvailabilityResponse>
<contextRegistrationResponseList>
<contextRegistrationResponse>
<contextRegistration>
<entityIdList>
<entityId type="Room" isPattern="false">
<id>Dorm</id>
</entityId>
</entityIdList>
<contextRegistrationAttributeList>
<contextRegistrationAttribute>
<name>temperature</name>
<type>degree</type>
<isDomain>false</isDomain>
<metadata>
<contextMetadata>
<name>ID</name>
<type>string</type>
<value/>
</contextMetadata>
<contextMetadata>
<name/>
<type/>
<value/>
</contextMetadata>
</metadata>
</contextRegistrationAttribute>
</contextRegistrationAttributeList>
<providingApplication>http://192.168.100.1:70
</providingApplication>
</contextRegistration>
</contextRegistrationResponse>
</contextRegistrationResponseList>
<errorCode>
<code>200</code>
<reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
<details xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Result</details>
</errorCode>
</discoverContextAvailabilityResponse>

2014-11-27 10:31:13,949 | INFO | (HttpConnectionClient.java:initializeConnection:218) | Connection Closed!
2014-11-27 10:31:13,987 | INFO | (XmlValidator.java:error:128) | 
ERROR
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'contextRegistration' is not complete. One of '
{registrationMetaData, providingApplication}
' is expected.
```

It is clearly seen by the received xml that at least the providingApplication is received but XMLValidator is not seeing this.

Answer (score -1):

In the meantime new releases with a lot of bug fixes have been issued, so your problem should be no longer existent.

In addition we added a configuration manager 'light' into the IoT broker, which enables you to use it standalone.

*P.S. I became aware of this help request only recently. I am very sorry that we therefore could not provide you an answer in due time.*